# what is meant by binary operation

Tags: abstract-algebra

What does it mean for a set $S$ which contains $a$ and $b$ to have an operation $*$ that assigns an element $a*b$?

I think it means for example, if $S = \{a,b,c,\ldots\}$ and  the set has the operation $*$ then you can use the operation with the objects in S to get $a*b$ and even $b*c$
is this what is meant by $S \times S\to S$?

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation).

Comment: The notation $S\times S\to S$ refers to a function from $S\times S$ to $S$, where $S\times S$ is the cartesian product of $S$ with itself.

Comment: Remember that $+$ and $\cdot$ are binary operations (add and multiply, resp.). Are you asking what this particular operation is in your example?

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $G$, a binary operation is a function $f : G \times G \to G$. As the comments suggest, familiar binary operations are $+$ and $\cdot$ which we traditionally see in grade school as $$+: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ $$(x,y) \mapsto +(x,y) :=x + y$$ and $$\cdot: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ $$(x,y) \mapsto \cdot(x,y) :=x \cdot y$$We know these particular binary operations as the addition and multiplication on the real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

A binary operation basically is an operation that takes in two inputs in a set and outputs something in the same set. For example, addition is a binary operation since you need two numbers to do it. In your example of $S\times S$, that is the Cartesian product. In case you don't know what that is, you can think of it as the set theory equivalent of multiplication, which is a binary operation. Click this link to learn  more about the Cartesian product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: I would rephrase your first sentence, a binary operation is more than a function that just takes two inputs. Its a function that takes two inputs from a set and gives an output in the *same* set. In other word, a binary operation *closes* on a set.

Comment: @TaylorRendon  Thank you for your feedback, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thank you for your feedback, I have edited the answer accordingly.